# Buttons on Adaptive card, posted via Graph API, are not sending event to messaging endpoint in MS Team

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am posting an adaptive card having couple of buttons via graph api `/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages` in msteams. Button click does not trigger event to endpoint mentioned in Bot.

```
buttons = [{
                    type :  "Action.Submit",
                    title: "Like",
                    data : { 
                        msteams : { 
                            type: "task/fetch"
                        },
                        data: "Like",
                        contentId: contentId
                    }
                },{
                    type :  "Action.Submit",
                    title: "Favorite",
                    data : { 
                        msteams : { 
                            type: "task/fetch"
                        },
                        data: "Favorite",
                        contentId: contentId,
                        siteId: siteId
                    }
                }]
```

When I click on the like/favourite button on adaptive card in msteams, it does nothing.
I am expecting an event at messaging endpoint that I added in bot.
Can someone help here. Thanks in advance.

I am new in MS Teams integration so not able to fine how to move forward. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

The only card action supported on cards sent through Graph is openurl.

Action.Submit and other actions are not supported when card is being sent through Graph API.